What is causing this damage to my siding?
This was a bubble like form I removed from a split in my garage wood.


Are you referring to the gash there?

I believe that was a sap vein.
You should clean it out to get all the debris out. Often it is easier to let the remaining sap dry and chip it out as a solid rather than the super sticky stuff it is.
When clean, fill it with wood filler. Then prime and paint.
It isn't some exotic problem or weird insect infestation. Just nature.

We see that often down here.
